# Sidenavigation Webview Link

Tags: android, menu, webview

I am playing around with the sample Sidenavigation apps from this website https://github.com/johnkil/SideNavigation. I have got the sample app to load on my phone without any issues. What I am trying to achieve though is to link the menu items to a various websites on webview. In the below code I just have one button in the sidenavigation panel. I have tried to link the button to webview using the following code, however when I load the app and click the button, the app crashes each time.

```
`case R.id.side_navigation_menu_item1:
 setContentView(R.layout.tab2);
 break;`
```

See below for the full code.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated as I have been stuck in a loop on this for a long time.

The following is the error I am getting when the app closes:
10-27 08:36:45.886: D/TilesManager(10889): new EGLContext from framework: 5182a990 
10-27 08:36:45.886: D/GLWebViewState(10889): Reinit shader
10-27 08:36:45.922: D/GLWebViewState(10889): Reinit transferQueue
10-27 08:36:46.050: D/dalvikvm(260): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2099K, 19% free 23941K/29255K, paused 2ms+10ms, total 217ms
10-27 08:36:46.050: D/dalvikvm(260): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 90ms
10-27 08:36:46.050: D/dalvikvm(260): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 50ms

Thank you.

**MainActivity.java**

```
`package com.devspark.sidenavigation.sample;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.devspark.sidenavigation.sample.R;
import com.devspark.sidenavigation.ISideNavigationCallback;
import com.devspark.sidenavigation.SideNavigationView;
import com.devspark.sidenavigation.sample.News;


public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity implements
    ISideNavigationCallback {

public static final String EXTRA_TITLE =                   "com.devspark.sidenavigation.sample.extra.MTGOBJECT";
public static final String EXTRA_RESOURCE_ID =   "com.devspark.sidenavigation.sample.extra.RESOURCE_ID";

private ImageView icon;
private SideNavigationView sideNavigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    icon = (ImageView) findViewById(android.R.id.icon);
    sideNavigationView = (SideNavigationView)     findViewById(R.id.side_navigation_view);
    sideNavigationView.setMenuItems(R.menu.side_navigation_menu);
    sideNavigationView.setMenuClickCallback(this);

    if (getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_TITLE)) {
        String title = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_TITLE);
        int resId = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_RESOURCE_ID, 0);
        setTitle(title);
        icon.setImageResource(resId);
    }

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        sideNavigationView.toggleMenu();
        break;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    return true;
}

public void onSideNavigationItemClick(int itemId) {
    switch (itemId) {


    case R.id.side_navigation_menu_item1:
        setContentView(R.layout.tab2);
                        break;

    default:
        return;
    }
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // hide menu if it shown
    if (sideNavigationView.isShown()) {
        sideNavigationView.hideMenu();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
/**
 * Start activity from SideNavigation.
 * 
 * @param title
 *            title of Activity
 * @param resId
 *            resource if of background image
 */
private void invokeActivity(String title, int resId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TITLE, title);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_RESOURCE_ID, resId);

    // all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this
    // Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a
    // new Intent.
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

startActivity(intent);
// no animation of transition
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}   
}`
```

**News.java**

```
`import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class News extends Activity {

private static String TAG = "WebViewTest";
private WebView mWebView;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
Log.i(TAG, "Entering onCreate");
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.clearCache(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
Log.i(TAG,"Exiting onCreate");
}
}`
```

**acitivity_main.xml**

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@android:id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image_desc"
    android:src="@drawable/android" />

<com.devspark.sidenavigation.SideNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/side_navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</RelativeLayout>`
```

**tab2.xml**

```
`<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
              android:scrollbarFadeDuration="5"
              android:fillViewport="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>`
```

**side_navigation_menu.xml**

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/side_navigation_menu_item1"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_side_navigation"
    android:title="News"/>

</menu>`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :). It might help people answer your question if you posted the error details.